# Using __init__ method to call class main functionality

Tags: python

I needed to encapsulate functions related to single responsibility of parsing and emiting messages to API endpoint so I have created class `Emitter`.

```py
class Emitter:
    def __init__(self, message: str) -> None:
        self.parsed = self.parse_message(message)
        self.emit_message(self.parsed)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_message(msg: str) -> str:
        ...  # parsing code

    @staticmethod
    def emit_message(msg: str) -> None:
        ...  # emitting code
```

In order to emit a message I call a short-lived instance of that class with `message` passed as argument to `__init__`.

```py
Emitter("my message to send")
```

`__init__` itself directly runs all necessary methods to parse and emit message.
Is it correct to use `__init__` to directly run the main responsibility of a class? Or should I use different solution like creating function that first instantiates the class and then calls all the necessary methods?

Comment: Why write a class if you don't want to use instances of it in some way? Just write a function.

Comment: "most Python code I've seen doesn't call classes directly but usually they make instance of a class or use some method from that class." I don't understand. "Calling the class" and "making an instance of the class" are the same thing. `Emitter("my message to send")` is how you create an `Emitter` instance. It seems like your question is about whether it's stylistically bad for the `__init__` method to have side effects. That is [too opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to be answered here, but personally my answer is that you should not create a class in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The way you instantiate an object is by calling the class.  If you're referring to the use of a static method, yes, that's perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: If you find having a class that useful, consider making the class itself an implementation detail, and have the user call a function that instantiates the class and then calls methods on it.

Comment: To go with Karl Knechtel's comment, it's one thing for `__init__` to have side effects, quite another to call it *just* for the side effects and discard the object immediately afterwards.

Comment: If you just want a namespace to collect the various methods used to implement `Emitter.__init__`, override `__new__` instead of `__init__. `__new__` doesn't *have* to create a new object and return it; it can just return `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to do the following at once:

1. initialize a class `Emitter` with an attribute `message`
2. parse the message
3. emit the message

IMO, a class entity is a good design choice since it allows granular control flow. Given that each step from above is discrete, I'd recommend executing them as such:

```
# Instantiate (will automatically parse)
e = Emitter('my message')

# Send the message
e.send_message()
```

You will need to redesign your class to the following:

```
class Emitter:
    def __init__(self, message: str) -> None:
        self.message = message
        self.parsed = self.parse_message(message)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_message(msg: str) -> str:
        ...  # parsing code

    # This should be an instance method
    def emit_message(msg: str) -> None:
        ...  # emitting code
```

Also, your `parse_message()` method could be converted to a validation method, but that's another subject.